# Azure function not working after deployment on Azure?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-triggers

I am totally new about Azure. And I have tried to build up the following architecture to show sensor data from Vicotee Device in power bi.
Vicotee Device -> LoraGateway -> Azure IOT Hub -> Azure Function -> Azure Event HUB=> Azure Stream Analytics => PowerBI.
I used visual studio code and wrote an azure function with python which decodes sensor data. There was no iot hub trigger to choose from and i used event hub trigger(should be same?). When i ran the function locally on my computer, everything is right.Sensor data decoded correctly and data were sent to event hub, stream analytics job and power bi. But after i disconnected the function locally and deployed the function(shows deploy successfully) on Azure through Visual studio code, there is no data flowing from IoT hub to event hub(there is data in Iot hub), so stream analytics has no data to output to power bi. I have to run azure function locally on my computer at same time to make everything work.I don't know what is the problem.Did i miss some part in the architecture?  Really appreciate if someone can help me. have Spent sometime on it already.

Answer (score 0):

Have you browsed the Kudu service and checked the deployed files? Browse the Kudu service by going to https:// ***yourfunctionname*** .scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI. Replace the ***yourfunctionname*** with the name of your function. Check if the `host.json` is built correctly. Also in that page, it will show the logs from the recent deployment.

Comment: Hi,thanks for ur reply. My functionname is EvenHubTrigger2. But when i typed https://eventhubtrigger2.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI it shows error 403:This web app is stopped.The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it again soon.

If you are the web app administrator, please find the common 403 error scenarios and resolution here.I am not the administrator,can it be that 'The site has reached a billing limit and your site has been disabled.'? but on Azure portal, this function still says:running

Comment: @sabrinacheng Usually this happens if your subscription has reached its spending limit. Settle the charges first, then return to your function and make sure it's running, then open the Kudu service that I mentioned before.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will ask azure administrator about the limit and follow it up.